# When running a compiled GCC file in the terminal, nothing happens

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I have Ubuntu 64 bit installed, and when I compile C files using the flags:

```
gcc -g -m32 -ansi -Wall -c -o *.o *.c
```

it compiles the files, but when I try to run them in the terminal, nothing happens.

So I decided to try to compile and run just one simple file without a makefile, with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation succeeds but when I try to run the file I get nothing...

Note: I already tried to install lib32gcc1, libc6-i386, and g++-multilib.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You're compiling but not linking?

Comment: If you want an executable, you mustn't have a `-c` switch in the command line. `gcc -g -m32 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -o prog main.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace -o *.o by -o programname. The -o parameter receives the executable name of the program you're generating. And here is gcc manual:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options

Answer (score 1):

For a simple test, leave every option out:

```
> cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}

> gcc test.c

> ./a.out
Hello World
```

and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you (already) have two object files `a.o` and `b.o`, their corresponding source file `a.c` and `b.c` and some common header `ch.h`; then your (incorrect) command line

```
 gcc -g -m32 -ansi -Wall -c -o *.o *
```

might be expanded as:

```
 gcc -g -m32 -ansi -Wall -c -o a.o b.o a.c b.c ch.h a.o b.o
```

<sup>(actually, that would be even worse, e.g. if you have some `Makefile` or some backup files from your editors like `a.c~`, as remarked by  William Pursell)</sup>

which would compile but not link, the files `b.o a.c b.c ch.h a.o b.o` which does not means much.

You should understand that the shell is expanding first the arguments before executing any `gcc` program (in a new process). To understand what is expanded, consider replacing `gcc` by `echo` (or by `gcc -v` which would show what is really happening)

Then, you should read the GCC documentation about [invoking GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

Actually, you need to spend several hours in reading, e.g. [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (which does have some mistakes perhaps) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Several wikipedia pages could also be useful to read.

Comment: Even worse, the command is probably expanded as `gcc -g ... a.o Makefile ...` since the OP mentions trying it without a makefile.